# Difference when concatenating strings in c++

Tags: c++

What's the difference, in terms of the underneath process, for the following two statements:

```
string strA = "stringA" + "stringB";
string strB = string("stringA") + string("stringB");
```

Comment: The main difference is that one compiles and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is pretty fundamental.

The type of `"stringA"` is `char const[8]`.

The type of `std::string("stringA")` is `std::string`.

There is no `operator+` defined that accepts two arguments of types `char const[]` or `char const*`.

Whereas, there are overloaded [`operator+(std::string, chat const*)` and `operator+(chat const*, std::string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

In other words, if you'd like to use `operator+` to concatenate string literals, the first or the second string must be `std::string`, so that it finds that overloaded `operator+`. E.g.

```
std::string("a") + "b" + "c" + "d"
// or 
"a" + std::string("b") + "c" + "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strA = "stringA" + "stringB";
```

error, cannot add two pointers

```
string strA = "stringA"  "stringB";
```

concatenates in compiler, same as "stringAstringB"

```
string strB = string("stringA") + string("stringB");
```

creates two std::string objects, adds them, returning a new object, and should then move construct into strB, so only 3 std::string constructors should be called in c++11.  Compiler will probably optimize all that away.

Comment: `s/compiler/preprocessor/`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not in my preprocessor (cpp (Debian 4.9.1-19) 4.9.1).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `cpp <<< '"foo" "bar"'` -> `"foo" "bar"`, i.e. the preprocessor did *not* concatenate the strings. (Same with `g++ -E`.)

Comment: @Biffen: Actually yeah fair point it doesn't happen until translation phase #6 and even phase #5 doesn't look all that preprocessory